Three points on the sides of an equilateral triangle
If three points P,Q,R are each (independently) chosen uniformly at random from the perimeter of an equilateral triangle, what is the probability that PQR is an acute-angled triangle?
(The points' positions are chosen independently, so it is possible that they all lie on the same side of the original triangle. In this case, triangle PQR will be degenerate and should not be considered acute-angled since one angle is 180 degrees.)
The probability that PQR is an acute-angled triangle is equal to $\frac{2}{3}\iiint_{[0,1]^{3}\cap \left \{  (x,y,z)|2x^2-2xy-xz+yz>0,2y^2-2xy+xz-yz>0,2z^2+2xy-xz-yz>0\right \}}1dxdydz+\frac{2}{9}\iiint_{[0,1]^{3}\cap \left \{  (x,y,z)|2x^2-xy+xz+yz-2x+y>0,2y^2-xy-xz-yz+2x-y>0,2z^2+xy+xz-yz-2x-y-2z+2>0\right \}}1dxdydz\approx 0.27$

Hello and welcome to Puzzling SE. [PQR] isn't always a triangle if you choose P, Q and R from the perimeter of an equilateral triangle (imagine, for instance, you pick all three points from the same side of that triangle). Please be more explicit if you want to evaluate the probability by counting those cases or not.

Yes,there is a 8/9 probability that  PQR is a triangle.

The result is well-known ROT13(bar sbhegu), but the method to evaluate the result is quite complex (it involves calculating distances over a coordinate system using integrals). I don't know if there is any purely geometric method to calculate that probability. Is it what you looking for? Otherwise this question is maybe more suitible for math.stackexchange.

There are three cases based on sharing sides—the hardest part is definitely when all three are on different sides.

Consider writing answer as answer as opposed to not hidden part of question. That said: integral expression looks a bit daunting which is an opportunity to explain step by step partially hidden in answer

@Pspl by the way the new edit seems to suggest a different answer.

@BenjaminWang, take a look at this link : mathpages.com. I think the result is the same as the distribution of the link because they regard only the angles for the distribution. But maybe I'm wrong... :(
